# Listen notification from some local event

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to listen a incomming notification such as : event from calendar, new message income, incomming phone, missed call, alarm clock ? 
All kind of these are local notification, aren't they ? 
So if i implement a broadcast receiver, i can listen all of these ?
My project is TTS program  which has to speech when the phone have notification, so i wonder whether my project is feasible or not
Thank for reading my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all are broadcast receivers and used widely. An event is broadcasted whenever one or more of these occur and you are notified. Just register your Breceiver and listen to these actions and you will be fine.

```
For example : 1) android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED -- for new sms received 
              2) android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE -- for new calll etc etc....
```

Comment: So can i read the content of the sms (because i want to speak it outloud) ?

Comment: yes, when the broadcast receiver will be notified that you have received a new sms, you will also get the message body which you can use in TTS :)

Comment: sorry, is it ok if i ask you another question, i still stuck at add event to calendar, whether i need a exist calendar app on android emulator or not ? because I still don't have any calendar app on my android emulator, so i think it is problem

Comment: yep, you need to get a calendar app installed. Look for popular calendar app such as google calendar and read about the intents they fire.